# Breadcrumb Arrow Icon in ImpressPages 4.x?

Tags: icons, delimiter, breadcrumbs, impresspages

Does anyone know how to get arrow icon as a delimiter between levels for ImpressPages CMS 4.0?

In previous version of ImpressPages (IP3.9) I've used this code in main.php:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
  <?php require_once(MODULE_DIR.'standard/breadcrumb/module.php');
    echo \Modules\standard\breadcrumb\Module::generateBreadcrumb('<img src="'.BASE_URL.THEME_DIR.THEME.'/img/arrow-right.png" />'); ?>
</div>
```

How to get it in IP4 on breadcrumb generation in main.php?

Answer (score 3):

In ImpressPages 4.0 separator is added through CSS. Here are the lines that make this magic:

```
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
    content: "/\00a0";
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: So, in the "content" I have to put path to the separator icon, e.g: "/img/arrow-right.png"... Am I right?  Thanks, for the response!